# How can I add custom hint in Linq2Sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, query-optimization, hint

I need add hint like 'with(index(PK_SomethingObjects))' for optimize my query.

How can I add it in linq2sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you don't. If you absolutely have to use hints, create a view and add it to your `DataContext`.